# I want to fill missing rows in a dataframe indexed by datetime with NAs across all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code where I can join two dataframes together, and overwrite the values in `df` with those in `df1`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create two dataframes 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(10, 4)), columns=(['Temp', 'Precip', 'Wind', 'Pressure']))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(11, 4)), columns=(['Temp', 'Precip', 'Wind', 'Pressure']))

df['Location'] =[2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
df1['Location'] =[0,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]

#create two different indices  which overlap
df.index = ["2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00"]
df1.index = ["2020-05-20 12:00:00","2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00"]

#make the datetime the index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
```

The dataframes look like this:

```
df
```

[image]

```
df1
```

[image]

df has values for locations 2,3,4,5 and 6 while df1 has values for locations 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. When I combine these together using cumcount and combine_first it removes the values for locations 0 and 1 as they are shorter in length than the other locations.

```
#merge and overwrite
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
df1 = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)

df = df.combine_first(df1).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df
```

[image]

This messes with the index by getting rid of the date sequence for each location, and putting the locations 0 and 1 in the dataframe on their own.

I want a dataframe that has the 18th, 19th and 20th for locations 0 and 1 and has NA values for these, like so:
[image]

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One idea should be append only `Location` to `MuliIndex` and then add missing rows by `unstack` with `stack` methods:

```
df = df.set_index(['Location'], append=True)
df1 = df1.set_index(['Location'], append=True)

df = (df.combine_first(df1)
        .unstack()
        .stack(dropna=False)
        .sort_index(level=[1,0])
        .reset_index(level=1))
        
print (df)
                     Location  Temp  Precip  Wind  Pressure
2020-05-18 12:00:00         0   NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN
2020-05-19 12:00:00         0   NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN
2020-05-20 12:00:00         0  18.0    10.0   2.0      29.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00         1   NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN
2020-05-19 12:00:00         1   NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN
2020-05-20 12:00:00         1  13.0    11.0  27.0      16.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00         2  17.0    13.0   6.0      23.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00         2  12.0     8.0  18.0      21.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00         2   5.0    29.0  15.0      22.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00         3  23.0     2.0  12.0       5.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00         3   1.0     2.0  18.0      20.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00         3  15.0    16.0   5.0      22.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00         4   3.0    23.0  10.0      29.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00         4  27.0     7.0   8.0       0.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00         4   4.0    18.0   6.0      27.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00         5  10.0    25.0   0.0      29.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00         5  26.0     9.0  24.0       2.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00         5   6.0    12.0   8.0       5.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00         6   9.0     1.0  17.0      17.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00         6  23.0     2.0  23.0      20.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00         6  10.0     0.0   6.0      10.0
```

Comment: EDIT: Thank you - this almost works for the data I gave, but it does not perform the overwriting function which is achieved by: `df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
df1 = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
 
df = df.combine_first(df1).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df` - I need df1 to overwrite the values in df also.